# RubyMine not showing the project folders with tree structure, it shows the tree structure for the excluded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine

I used the RubyMine version 2020.3, when I opened it, the project structure is showing. I restarted and reset the file settings, but not working[image]

Comment: Open that folder again. You have to reopen the exact folder, it will work. It's not actually a problem.

Comment: I can't able to open that folder.

Comment: Click File->Close Project then you will get another window in which you will be seeing all the project you have opened so far. Select your project and open it. Or On the top, you will be seeing three buttons one is New Project, Open, Get from VCS. Choose open and open your project, it will load your project properly.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I tried what you told, but it's not working, then I goto preference -> project structure-> add a project, then it shows the tree structure. It's working fine now.
Thanks for your response and info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced same problem,This solution worked for me.
Solution:
"Reset your IDE settings, delete .idea folder on your local"